# Set precision in display format for floating point numbers in dtype

Tags: python, floating-point, dtype

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
72,35,0,33.6,6,148,0.627,50,1
66,29,0,26.6,1,85,0.351,31,0
64,0,0,23.3,8,183,0.672,32,1
...
```

I am trying to read the values from this file using the following line of code:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=float)
```

My problem is that now my dataframe looks like this (scientific notation):

```
7.200000000000000000e+01,3.500000000000000000e+01,0.000000000000000000e+00,3.360000000000000142e+01,6.000000000000000000e+00,1.480000000000000000e+02,6.270000000000000018e-01,5.000000000000000000e+01,1.000000000000000000e+00
6.600000000000000000e+01,2.900000000000000000e+01,0.000000000000000000e+00,2.660000000000000142e+01,1.000000000000000000e+00,8.500000000000000000e+01,3.509999999999999787e-01,3.100000000000000000e+01,0.000000000000000000e+00
6.400000000000000000e+01,0.000000000000000000e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,2.330000000000000071e+01,8.000000000000000000e+00,1.830000000000000000e+02,6.720000000000000417e-01,3.200000000000000000e+01,1.000000000000000000e+00
```

Is there anyway I can set the `dtype` value in my code to avoid scientific notation while still reading the data as floating point numbers?

Comment: precision and display format are 2 different things... which one really bothers you?

Comment: @Julien I have a problem with display format, since I have to keep checking the data, this format makes it hard to read and when I save the dataframe to another csv that file is also in scientific notation

Answer (score 0):

A couple potential suggestions:

1. Use np.loadtxt instead of np.genfromtxt

   dataset = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=', fmt="%2.3f", delimiter=",")
2. Import python's "decimal" module for precision and convert the scientific notation string into a float decimal value.

Comment: np.loadtxt also returns the scientific notation. I have not tried decimal module but since I have a lot of data I'm looking for a way to initially read the data as floats with 2-3 decimal points